# Using exponential decay function to predict multiple outcomes with the same decay rate, same initial value

Tags: statistics, exponential-function

So, I have the same initial value $x_{2015}$, let's say at $t_{2015}$ and multiple ending values $x_{2030}$ at say $t_{2030}$. For example:

$x_{2015} = 2500$  $x_{2030} = 1300$
$x_{2015} = 2500$  $x_{2030} =890$
$x_{2015} = 2500$  $x_{2030} = 1240$
$x_{2015} = 2500$  $x_{2030} = 1100$

I want to use the **same decay rate** $r$, $x_{2015}$ and $x_{2030}$ as input into the exponential decay function $y = a(1-r)^{t-t_0}$ at every 5 years time step to calculate the values from 2015 to 2100. So going from 2015 to 2020, 2025, at $t=2030$, I want the function to reproduce the $x_{2015}$ and $x_{2030}$ values used as input into the function.

So far, I have manipulated the exponential decay function like this:
$$x_t = x_{2015} + \frac{(x_{2030} - x_{2015})}{(1-r)}(1-r^\frac{t - t_{2015}}{t_{2030} - t_{2015}})$$

So at $t = t_{2015}$ I get $x_{2015}$  and at $t = t_{2030}$, the $(1-r)$ cancels out and I get $x_{2030}$. So in the end whichever values I use for $x_{2030}$, $x_{2015}$ and the decay rate $r$, it will reproduce the 2015 and 2030 values and along with the other values at each $t$.

The problem is, I am not sure if this makes enough sense, is there another way I can do this or is this the only way?. I have looked at this function $y_t = Be^{-mt}$, but I can't find a way to even manipulate this to give me what the other equation is giving me above.

Answer (score 0):

Given values at two times you can compute the decay rate from the ratio of those two values and the time between them.  As you have different final values, each one will give a different decay rate.  You have two choices:  accept the differences between the measurements and compute a different decay rate for each of the pieces of data or believe that the four end values correspond to noise on a true value with a true decay rate.  You could use the mean or the geometric mean of the end values to compute a decay rate.

The correct equation for exponential decay is $Be^{-mt}$.  If we measure $t$ in units of five years you can evaluate $B,m$ for any of your data.  If we set the zero of time as $2015$ then $B=2500$.  For the first pair of data then $$e^{-3m}=\frac {1300}{2500}\\m=\frac {\ln \frac {1300}{2500}}{-3}\approx 0.21798$$ and you can plug in $t=1,2$ to get the values for $2020,2025$

Comment: Thanks Ross, I have considered the first choice, estimating the different decay rates for each pair. But here am assuming, we have a true decay rate and those 2030 values are guesses for what the true value will be in 2030 following that decay rate. For the second choice, if I use the mean/geometric mean of the end values to compute a decay rate, plugging that rate into the equation, it will not reproduce my 2030 end values.

Comment: If you have a single decay rate, it can only predict one value in 2030. If you have four guesses you can't reproduce them all and should not want to reproduce any of them.  You should want to come up with some average guess and reproduce that.  You can do that by following my calculation, replacing $1300$ with your guess for the value in 2030